# Watir::ElementCollection click action in loop

Tags: ruby, loops, watir-webdriver

Going off the example from the documentation http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/0.6.11/Watir/ElementCollection#each-instance_method, I am trying to click each element on the page that has the same class. 
This is a code snippet of what I've come up with so far:

```
@b.divs(:class => 'portal-thumbnail-card').each do |div|    
    @b.div(:class => 'portal-thumbnail-card').click
    puts 'foo' 
    # my puts statement outputs 'foo' 6 times (matches the number of elements with that class)
    # right now this only clicks on the FIRST element, having issues with the other part :(    
end
```

Even though this doesn't involve any page reloading, are click actions possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are locating the `div` to click during each iteration of the loop. In English, your code actually says, "for each `div` element with the class 'portal-thumbnail-card', click the first `div` on the page with class 'portal-thumbnail-card'."

What you actually want to do is click the `div` element that is the subject of each iteration:

```
@b.divs(:class => 'portal-thumbnail-card').each do |div|    
  div.click
  puts 'foo' 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `divs` method returns a `Watir::DivCollection`, which is a collection of `Watir::Div` objects.  For example:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto('http://example.org')

divs = b.divs
puts divs.class
#=> Watir::DivCollection

divs.each { |d| puts d.class}
#=> Watir::Div
```

So--within your iterator--you want to refer to the block-local variable (i.e. `div.click`) instead of the browser's instance variable (i.e. `@b.div(:class => 'portal-thumbnail-card').click`)

Answer (score 0):

use **flash** method for see element what you try click

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "data:text/html,#{DATA.read}"

browser.divs(:class => 'portal-thumbnail-card').each do |div|
#   browser.div(:class => 'portal-thumbnail-card').flash #you variant
    div.flash #correct variant
    puts 'foo'
end

browser.close

__END__

<html>
    <div class='portal-thumbnail-card'>
        <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class='portal-thumbnail-card'>
        <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class='portal-thumbnail-card'>
        <button id="button3">Button 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class='portal-thumbnail-card'>
        <button id="button4">Button 4</button>
    </div>
    <div class='portal-thumbnail-card'>
        <button id="button5">Button 5</button>
    </div>
</html>
```